# Why is my first program using dev-c++ not working?

Tags: compiler-errors, dev-c++

I have installed devc++ and written a basic hello world program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main
{
   cout<<"hello";
   return 0;
}
```

It is my run. However I am getting the following errors while running the code

```
3   1   D:\cpp\helloworld.cpp   [Warning] extended initializer lists only 
                                available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
4   4   D:\cpp\helloworld.cpp   [Error] 'cout' was not declared in this scope
5   4   D:\cpp\helloworld.cpp   [Error] expected unqualified-id before 
                               'return'
6   1   D:\cpp\helloworld.cpp   [Error] expected declaration before '}' token
```

Someone please help !

Comment: What part of this is a merge sort?

Comment: You didn't declare the arguments for `main`.

Comment: There are so many hello world programs out there... how is it possible to still do it wrong? I'm afraid the tooltip text of the downvote button applies to your case.

Comment: @trincot the problem is probably with my dev c++ settings and that is what i wanted you to debug.

Comment: The code is invalid, has nothing to do with your IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first line of code, you use `#include<stdio.h>` which is a [c preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) directive, but in main function you use `cout<<"hello";` which is a C++ code.

For a C code, you need to use something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

And in the C++ (Read at [C++ Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Language)), you need to use something like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
return 0;
}
```

Stuff like this should be easy to find on cplusplus.com
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/49600/